# Sequelize: How to add 12 hours from now

Tags: typescript, date, sequelize-typescript

I want to set my date end default value to the currentDate + 12 hours

i try some stuff but that's not work, if someone could help me

```
 dateEnd: {
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: sequelize.fn('NOW') + 'INTERVAL 12 HOUR',

            allowNull: false
        }
```

thanks

Comment: @MarkRobson That's not what the question author wants. In your case default value will be the time of executing code with this definition and it will not change for each new record.

Comment: What DB do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sequelize.literal` to define a default value that uses DB functions:

```
dateEnd: {
            type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('NOW() + INTERVAL 12 hour'),
            allowNull: false
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ INTERVAL '12 hours',`

Comment: I fixed a literal value